# Search base on buttons

Tags: button, search, icons

I am trying to build a search base on multiple parameters.
Can you help me or guide me I am quite lost.

The idea will be something like the URL below:

https://www.evaneos.de/info/reiseziele-finden/?months=may

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a question and details, to community to answer that question.

Comment: Hi Sarthak, the question is how can I create a search form working with only buttons.